# Collapsible in jquery mobile doesn't work in android webview but works in fiddler

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have created a collapsible section in fiddler using jquery mobile, which work perfectly fine and all the section does collapse 
    https://jsfiddle.net/ashishrawat/cduhkLm0/

```
However when i take the same page and display it in webview, it doesn't work. I have inspected it in chrome and I get the same element(html) as jsfiddle, excluding the header, also there is no error in console. 
My page rendering code in android is pretty standard
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(
                        inspectView.new SurveyJSInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
                //webView.loadUrl(mSurveyUrl);
                //webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", fileContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
                webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/index.html", fileContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
                webView.setInitialScale(1);
                webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
                webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

HEader section 
     
                 
            
            
            
           
            
            
            $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
                $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
            });

Only difference which i could see is fiddler is using jquery 1.4.4 while i am locally using 1.4.5 However i don't think that matters.
Please suggest !

Comment: How does your index.html look like? Are you using?   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: Index.html only show javascripts ...element file contain the meta tags in header.. which i have pasted in main question as this comment has character limit. Please suggest

Comment: Make sure you libraries (JQuery) are loading properly, maybe using file:// protocol is throwing security errors.  Try adding an image next to your index.html and try loading it on the page to see if it shows.

Comment: yes it does, i tried surrounding a div with h1 tag to see if jquery working and it worked !

Comment: what if you host the form on a server? just for testing of course.

Comment: yes it works !! thats really strange !when i put the resultant code in html file and  refer in my webview using same method, it works !!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason was simple. The page is modified after dom is loaded hence need to refesh the form using.

$("#formid").trigger("create");